# 404 error when requesting from NZ and AUS servers

Tags: javascript, curl, httprequest, spotify, cdn

When requesting `/me` or `/browse/featured-playlists` from the Spotify HTTP API, I receive a 404 error.

I am based in New Zealand and have tested this on 5 different computers (Mac, Linux and Windows) with more HTTP clients than I have fingers (Chrome, Firefox, CURL, Firebug, Postman, jQuery).

I attempted the CURL request from an Australian based server (I'm a web developer with access to other servers). Same deal, 404 not found. **But here's the kicker: when attempting the very same request from a US-based server, it worked perfectly fine, every time!**

This indicates a CDN type issue, however this can only be confirmed by Spotify Developer staff.

This issue affects my popular Mopidy HTTP client, Iris (https://github.com/jaedb/Iris) that uses the Spotify API quite heavily.

To replicate, try this CURL request on a NZ or Australian internet connection:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/featured-playlists" -H "Authorization: Bearer ENTER_YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
```

Comment: Can you ping api.spotify.com from the servers? Maybe it's a provider issue or DNS issue. Maybe a DNS flush would help: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/

Comment: The issue doesn't affect the whole api.spotify.com domain, just a number of endpoints. That what I find particularly baffling. A DNS or connection issue would affect all endpoints. I have tested across a multitude of ISPs as well so I'm confident it's not a client-side issue.

Comment: It gets weirder. After repeated testing I've found that requests will occasionally return successfully (`HTTP 200`), but then will revert to failing (`HTTP 404`). I've tested this in Postman and have recorded the issue in action: https://youtu.be/ul44jDOqs3Q. I repeated this test using US and EU VPNs and all requests are successful (`HTTP 200`).